# left join query keep a column empty

Tags: mysql, join

I have a two table called `PaymentMaster` and `PaymentDetails` and two table joined by `receiptID` column. This is my query

```
   SELECT pm.receiptID
          , pm.recievedAmount
          , pd.invono
          , pd.paidAmount 
     FROM PaymentMaster pm 
LEFT JOIN PaymentDetail pd ON pd.receiptID = pm.receiptID
```

following query provide me this result

[image]

note that there are two records in `PaymentDetails` regarding receiptID `PAY0002`. That is why two records show for `PAY0002`. (`INV0001,INV0002`).

the issue is, I do not want to print `PAY0002` in two rows. if the id is same then the column should be empty.The end result should be like this

[image]

Comment: What you are trying to achieve belongs in the presentation layer, not the SQL layer. You are not ordering by anything so the position of INV0002 is only below INV0001 by accident. There is no absolute guarantee that it will always appear in the same place, and in the SQL context, "invono" has no meaning without its receiptID.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GROUP BY](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-group-by-clause.htm) keyword for grouping them, your query will become something like this

```
  SELECT pm.receiptID
      , pm.recievedAmount
      , pd.invono
      , pd.paidAmount 
 FROM PaymentMaster pm LEFT JOIN PaymentDetail pd ON pd.receiptID = pm.receiptID GROUP BY pd.receiptID
```

Comment: group by will remove the whole rows. i just want to remove the two column values

Comment: You will have to handle that in the HTML/view where you are displaying the data

Comment: is there any way i can do this via query instead of the html

Comment: You can use group_concat to group data but still it would not be in exactly the same format you want, try the following 
SELECT pm.receiptID
      , pm.recievedAmount
      , group_concat(pd.invono)
      , group_concat(pd.paidAmount)
 FROM PaymentMaster pm LEFT JOIN PaymentDetail pd ON pd.receiptID = pm.receiptID GROUP BY pd.receiptID

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variable to control what you display

```
drop table if exists pm,pd;
create table pm(id varchar(8), amt int);
create table pd(id varchar(8), amt int);

insert into pm values ('aaa',1000),('bbb','100');
insert into pd values ('aaa',100),('aaa',100),('bbb',100);


Select case when rn = 1 then pmid else '' end as pmid,
         case when rn = 1 then pmamt else '' end as pmamt,
         pdid,pdamt
from
(
select pm.id pmid,pm.amt pmamt,
        pd.id pdid, pd.amt pdamt
        ,if(pm.id<> @p, @rn:=1,@rn:=@rn+1) rn
        ,@p:=pm.id
from pm
join pd on pd.id = pm.id
,(select @rn:=0,@p:=0) rn
) s
```